# mining DNA barcodes from Genebank/BOLD per location

Tags: phylogenetics, barcode

Is there a method to download all the sequences for a particular geographic region (Panama) for 'DNA barcode' sequences (ITS2, rbcL or trnL). Hopefully, the specimen collection location will include this information.

I want to use the Genbank sequences to create a DNA reference database of local plants for eDNA studies.

Comment: Hi @uvnomad yes its easy, but what does your reference database do? Is it for taxonomy of all plants?

Comment: Great, how is it done? The reference is used to compare sequences of unknown plants (eDNA) to the known sequences of locally occuring plants.